# Torque control of servo motor

Tags: control-engineering

I have an EtherCAT loop with a servo motor that is controlled at 2kHz. An outer loop running at 1kHz has to calculate the demanded torque for the servo motor and send it through UDP.

The motor needs to respond to a request that includes demands for position, velocity and acceleration.

I need to implement a control loop that is able to convert the three parameters (position, velocity and acceleration) in a torque number. If I calculate the force starting from the velocity, then I need to control overshoots and promptly reduce the demanded torque without undershooting. If I calculate the force from the position, then I loose the velocity and acceleration component.

What are the best resources to read to start this project? Or what block diagrams are best suitable for this use?

Let me know if I need to be more specific

**EDIT:** The load applied to the motor is human force changing between 0daN and 60daN. The lever length is 0.2m with an angle that can be approximated to 90deg for the whole travel

---

Some numbers: the motor has a gear ratio of 1:8 and the travel limit is 27 deg (216 deg at motor shaft). It needs to be reactive enough to change velocity (at gear output) from 125deg/s to -50deg/s in 60ms with a tolerance in demanded position of 10%. The motor itself has a specified maximum velocity of 720deg/s and max continuous torque of 240Nm at gear output. The servo drive runs at 8kHz

Comment: review the basic control theory. characterize your load. servo control can be non trivial unfortunately, but if you have excess power you can simplify your life a lot by adding mechanical damping. try 2 cascaded loops: one for velocity, one for position.

Comment: @PeteW thank you for your comment. I have added a description of the motor load. I am thinking to start designing with only mechanical linkage connected to the motor and no extra load. Reach required movement precision, then start tweaking with added load. Shall I think the full picture from the beginning?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'd like to point out that for DC motors, torque is proportional to motor current.

Comment: @Afe - "Shall I think the full picture from the beginning" - yes.

Comment: @EricS The torque loop is already implemented by supplier of the motors

Comment: Doesn’t stop you from measuring the motor current.